# Gulp 4 BrowSersync not refreshing the webpage when SCSS files changed

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I just started to use Gulp with BrowserSync.
Please, help me with following issue: When I save my SCSS files BrowserSync not refreshes the webpage but saves files OK. Here is what happening in the console:

> [21:37:48] Starting 'css'...
>
> [Browsersync] 1 file changed (main.min.css)
>
> [21:37:48] Finished 'css' after 206 ms

So no message

> "[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers..."

This problem only with SCSS files, JS and HTML work correctly. Here is my gulpfile.js:

```js
let project_folder = require("path").basename(__dirname);
let source_folder = "#src";

let fs = require('fs');

let path = {
    build: {
        html: project_folder + "/",
        css: project_folder + "/css/",
        js: project_folder + "/js/",
        img: project_folder + "/images/",
        fonts: project_folder + "/fonts/",
    },
    src: {
        html: [source_folder + "/*.html", "!" + source_folder + "/_*.html"],
        css: source_folder + "/styles/main.scss",
        js: source_folder + "/js/main.js",
        img: source_folder + "/images/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}",
        fonts: source_folder + "/fonts/*.{ttf,otf,woff,woff2}",
    },
    watch: {
        html: source_folder + "/**/*.html",
        css: source_folder + "/styles/**/*.scss",
        js: source_folder + "/js/**/*.js",
        img: source_folder + "/images/**/*.{jpg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}"
    },
    clean: "./" + project_folder + "/"
}

let { src, dest } = require('gulp'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    browsersync = require("browser-sync").create(),
    include = require('gulp-include'),
    del = require("del"),
    scss = require("gulp-sass"),
    autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer"),
    group_media = require("gulp-group-css-media-queries"),
    clean_css = require("gulp-clean-css"),
    rename = require("gulp-rename"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify-es").default,
    imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin"),
    webp = require('gulp-webp'),
    webphtml = require('gulp-webp-html'),
    webpcss = require("gulp-webpcss"),
    svgSprite = require('gulp-svg-sprite');

function browserSync(params) {
    browsersync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./" + project_folder + "/"
        },
        port: 3000,
        notify: false
    })
}

function html() {
    return src(path.src.html)
        .pipe(include())
        .pipe(webphtml())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function css() {
    return src(path.src.css)
        .pipe(
            scss({
                outputStyle: "expanded"
            })
        )
        .pipe(
            group_media()
        )
        .pipe(
            autoprefixer({
                overrideBrowserslist: ["last 5 versions"],
                cascade: true
            })
        )
        .pipe(webpcss())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(clean_css())
        .pipe(
            rename({
                extname: ".min.css"
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function js() {
    return src(path.src.js)
        // .pipe(fileinclude())
        .pipe(include())
        .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(
            uglify()
        )
        .pipe(
            rename({
                extname: ".min.js"
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function images() {
    return src(path.src.img)
        .pipe(
            webp({
                quality: 70
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
        .pipe(src(path.src.img))
        .pipe(
            imagemin({
                progressive: true,
                svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
                interlaced: true,
                optimizationLevel: 3 // 0 to 7
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function fonts() {
    return src(path.src.fonts)
        .pipe(dest(path.build.fonts));
};

gulp.task('svgSprite', function () {
    return gulp.src([source_folder + '/iconsprite/*.svg'])
        .pipe(svgSprite({
            mode: {
                stack: {
                    sprite: "../icons/icons.svg",  //sprite file name
                    example: true
                }
            },
        }
        ))
        .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
})


function watchFiles(params) {
    gulp.watch([path.watch.html], html);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.css], css);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.js], js);
    gulp.watch([path.watch.img], images);
}

function clean(params) {
    return del(path.clean);
}

let build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(js, css, html, images, fonts));
let watch = gulp.parallel(build, watchFiles, browserSync);

exports.fonts = fonts;
exports.images = images;
exports.js = js;
exports.css = css;
exports.html = html;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = watch;
```

Comment: were you able to find out the issue with this?